# How to share SignalR singleton between multiple instance of Simple Injector

Tags: singleton, signalr, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, rebus

I'm using Simple Injector for IoC and Rebus, service bus, to dispatch events saved in multiple queues (topic).
Rebus needs to be configured with a new **SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter** for each queue.

```
var bus = Configure.With(new SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter(container))
```

In this configuration phase is not possible to pass the same instance of Simple injector container neither the same instance of container adapter (the container rises an error of multiple registration of IBus).

I'm also using SignalR as one of the events ' handlers to dispatch events to the clients.
Following [this SignalR configuration tutorial](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#server)  I set up several hub and relative event notifier (one for each [bounded context](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) in the application).
Using the classical singleton pattern, as shown in the tutorial example, is easy to pass the same instance of notifier to the various instances of containers:
`container.RegisterSingleton(Finishing.Notification.Notifier.Instance);`

Now I would like to delegate the instance creation to the Simple Injector container (only one), so I started to follow [this tutorial](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection):

```
        container.RegisterSingleton<Finishing.Notification.Notifier>();
        container.Register(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Finishing.Notification.NotificationHub>().Clients);
```

The issue is that, in this way, I will have n instance of notifier one for each container instance (deeply regrettable).

I know that I can solve this [using a master container as Abstract Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909540/3757210), but I'm looking for a more specific solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [override existing registrations](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) to resolve the original error *multiple registration of IBus*?

Comment: Can I ask, why specifically you would like to avoid the service locater pattern?  It would seem like that would be a good fit for your requirement.

Comment: @ravi I'd like to avoid service locator because I know it is an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: @ilcorvo, you will have to think about it in the context of your solution.  It is not a anti-pattern in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to delegate the instance creation to the Simple Injector containers
>
> (...)
>
> The issue is this way I will have n instance of notifier one for each container instance.

So you would like for each container to create the singleton instance, but it is a problem that each container holds an instance of the singleton... isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Probably I was not clear: I definitely don’t like to have multiple instances of the notifier classes, so I'm asking for a tips to pass instance from the master container to the child containers, avoiding service locator pattern.

Comment: Ah, then I get it. So it's not really related to Rebus, it's more of a SimpleInjector question?